# Hash Tables in clisp.Storing lists in hashtables

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuh4U.jpg

why is the hash table returning nil.Doesn't hashtables work for lists.

Answer (score 0):

The default hash-table uses `eql` for key comparison.  You can choose between `eq`, `eql`, `equal` and `equalp`.  For lists, you need `equal` or `equalp`.  Look them up in the [Hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Front/X_Symbol.htm), as well as `make-hash-table`.